# What is the name of the double square brackets command in shell?

Tags: shell

Apologies if this question has already been asked previously. I haven’t managed to find an answer on google/stack overflow.

I know that the single square brackets operator is called test and thus `man test` can be used to consult its man page or `which test` to find where the file is located in the OS.

What is the equivalent name for the double square brackets command?

*It would be useful to run the man command on it from time to time*. :-/

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Chopo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-bracket `[[ ... ]]` tests are a special piece of shell syntax, not an external command. You can read about them by searching for the phrase "**CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS**" in the bash or zshmisc man page.

The expression inside the double brackets is parsed differently from a normal command line, so you couldn't create an external command that behaves the same way even if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks @wumpus-q-wumbley, Looks like the ksh man pages on our version of AIX are a bit poor in comparison to what you cool kids on in the bash world get. I guess I can at least Google the correct search term now, kind of...

Answer (score 3):

- `[` has the long name: `/usr/bin/[`
- `[[` is a shell keyword

In Bash the `[` is a builtin command as well as an executable. `[[` is just a keyword to Bash - e.g.: using `type`:

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[

$ type -a [[
[[ is a shell keyword
```

More details on the unix stackexchange:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is a keyword in Bash (and a reserved word in POSIX). It is not a separate command and doesn't have its own `man` page.

In the Bash manual, it is referred to as "the `[[` compound command" and "the `[[` conditional command" in various places.

You can find it in `man bash` in the section **Compound Commands**.

Further information on its usage can be found in the **Conditional Expressions** section.

Comment: Thanks @Tom_Fenech. So does that mean it is a built in command to ksh/bash as opposed to a standalone application in /usr/bin/ like the single `brackets` test command. – I’m a ksh user and the ksh manual doesn’t seem to be as rich as the bash one.